# Php styling error/warnings messages

Tags: php, colors, warnings

Im writing some PHP code on website with dark background and whenever I get php error(im new to php, so quite often) I can barely see it. Is there any way to style error/warnings messages or even change color?

Comment: I ........ don't get what you're asking; where's your code?

Comment: *"Is there any way to style error/warnings messages or even change color?"* - Yes.

Comment: My code doesnt matter actually, I wanna color the errors that appear on top each website with any php error

Answer (score 0):

Use [Xdebug](https://xdebug.org/docs/all):

> Xdebug replaces PHP's var_dump() function for displaying variables.
>   Xdebug's version includes different colors for different types and
>   places limits on the amount of array elements/object properties,
>   maximum depth and string lengths. There are a few other functions
>   dealing with variable display as well.